# When a transfer is on-going on Send Anywhere is there any way to see what code (6-digit number) was used?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, file-transfer

When a transfer is on-going on [Send Anywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estmob.android.sendanywhere&hl=en) is there any way to see what code (6-digit number) was used to initiate the transfer from the uploader side?

[image]

I use Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III with a rooted Android 4.1.2.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.